# Python plotly animate a series of heatmap

Tags: python, neural-network, visualization, plotly

I have this code that traverse on a neural network layer weights (which are saved for each epoch), and using plotly I am creating nice heatmaps (X - neuron in layer l, Y - weights associated with the neuron) heatmaps for each layer, epoch.

What I really want in the end, is to animate (play a sequence of heatmap associated to a specific network layer) to watch the progression of neuron connections.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement a plotly animation based on these set of heatmap as produced by my code (result should be either an mp4 or mpeg file or an html file that embeds an plotly animation)

```
 for i, epoch in enumerate(files):
    pkl_file = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "weights_visual_raw_data", epoch), 'rb')
    weights = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    pkl_file.close()
    weights = [x for x in weights if x]
    for l, layer in enumerate(weights):
        if l >= len(weights)-2:
            layer_weights = layer[0]
        else:
            layer_weights = layer[1]
        trace = go.Heatmap(z=layer_weights)
        data = [trace]
        plot(data,auto_open=False, filename=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
                                         "weights_dynamic_visualization",
                                         "layer"+str(l),
                                         "weights_epoch_" + str(i)))
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the examples here? https://plot.ly/python/animations/

Comment: yes, I'm not sure if I should create a grid and if so - how should I represent the heatmap object in the grid